# Is it idiomatic to say "I am also not sure"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In my other post I said

> I am not sure if I did it in the right way... I am **also** not sure if I used the right term to refer to ...

where I put an adverb **also** in there.

I was trying to express my another uncertainty. And then I am worried about whether the place of the **also** is grammatical.

Therefor, I searched that on Google Ngram, which turns out to be not as common.

[image]

So, is it grammatical and idiomatic to say "I am also not sure"?

Comment: Quite correct, or "I am also unsure..." is equally valid.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you. Does "correct" means "grammatically correct" or it is also idiomatic?

Comment: Yes, though at one time there might have been  quibble about splitting a verb... "I also am not sure," though pedantically correct, is less colloquial.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Actually, I didn't think of "I also am not sure" before you mentioned it. However, I did search "I am not also sure" and got none on Google Ngram and [one hit on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/191999/109190).

Comment: Sometimes I hear "equally sure/unsure".

Comment: "I also am not sure" would be a bad choice, because it could mean that both I and another person are unsure.

Comment: To convey the meaning of "both I and another person are unsure", I guess the expression "I am not sure either" is more common, right?